# Porque laravel me esta detectando este error en un script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Nose porque Laravel me esta detectando un error que se encuentra dentro de un script de javascript en mi vista, pero a simple vista no parece haber ningun tipo de error.
El error que me devuelve es el siguiente:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'columns' (T_STRING), expecting ')'
```

Este es mi script donde detecta el error:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#datatable').Datatable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'ajax': "{{ route('backend.products.view) }}",
            'columns': [
                {'data': 'id'},
                {'data': 'brandName'},
                {'data': 'modelName'}
            ],
        });

        $('.filter-input').keyup(function(){
            table.column( $(this).data('column'))
                .search( $(this).val())
                .draw();
        });
    })
</script>
```

Este script se encuentra despues del ultimo @endsection y esta en una vista de blade.

Alguien sabe porque se esta produciendo este error?

Comment: Inicialmente falta una comilla de cierre donde invocas por su nombre a la ruta

Comment: sobra o falta comilla aqui: `{{ route('backend.products.view) }}`